# Show that if $A$ is closed in $X$ and $B$ is closed in $Y$, then $A\times B$ is closed in $X\times Y$.

Tags: general-topology

Show that if $A$ is closed in $X$ and $B$ is closed in $Y$, then $A\times B$ is closed in $X\times Y$.

Comment: Hint: what is the complement of $A \times B$ in $X \times Y$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

$$(X\times Y)\setminus(A\times B)=\Big((X\setminus A)\times Y\Big)\cup\Big(X\times(Y\setminus B)\Big)$$

Comment: When did you replace "HINT" by the nice-looking "**Hint**"?

Comment: @Peter: I always use HINT when it’s at the very beginning of the answer, and usually when it comes later. Call it a signature, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ \left\{a_n \right\}_{n=0}^{\infty}\subseteq A, \left\{b_n\right\}\subseteq B$, be series, which converge respectively to the limits $a,b$. Since A is closed, then $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_n=a\in A$, and similarly, since B is closed $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n=b \in B$. Therefore, if we define $ x_n=(a_n,b_n)$, then $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n, \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n)=(a,b)\in A\times B$, and therefore, $A\times B$ is closed in $X\times Y$.

Let's note that this is the direction if this is a metric space. Otherwise, we have to show that $ (X\times Y)/(A\times B)$ is open, by using the fact that $X/A, Y/B$ are open.

Comment: The correct term in English is *sequence*, not *series*.

Comment: We're not assuming this is a metric space, so sequences are not really the way to go.